# Protecting API from random calls

Tags: python, flask

I have an API running with CORS setup.
It all works fine, but lately I've been seeing a huge amount of 404 calls to my API, with what seems to be an automated attack. Some examples:

```
[27/Nov/2019:02:24:30 +0000] "GET /.env HTTP/1.1" 404 233 "-" "curl/7.47.0"
[27/Nov/2019:02:11:46 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 233 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0"
[27/Nov/2019:02:11:40 +0000] "GET /mysql/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 233 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0"
[27/Nov/2019:01:19:59 +0000] "POST /editBlackAndWhiteList HTTP/1.1" 404 233 "-" "ApiTool"
[27/Nov/2019:02:11:41 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin/scripts/_setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 233 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0"
```

I have literally thousands of those, with slight variations on the endpoints and paths. I don't know much about security, but it seems like so sort of attack. Fortunately none of those found any "real" endpoint, but I'm concerned I may have some sort of breach and that eventually they will.

What can I do to prevent this? Even if I establish a more solid security route, is there anyway to avoid the fake calls altogether? I remeber seeing something like blocking the IP after a given number of 404's, maybe this is the way to go?

If anyone could shed some light on the issue I would be very grateful.

Comment: I would suggest looking into things like fail2ban and nginx to serve your app to the world wide internet. With the correct configuration, certain ip addresses are blacklisted automatically.

Comment: thanks mate. I normally used fail2ban on my DO droplet, but things are less flexible with ElasticBeanstalk, so I'm really familiar if I should add scripts at the server level (f2b and nginx) or if there was something I could do with my code.